# Book about a traveling gypsy woman who makes potions and has visions

Tags: story-identification

I've been trying to remember this book for years. I read it around 2003. It was a fantasy book set in a historical 1800s England type setting. (I think it was England but I'm not sure).

The gypsy inherited her wagon from her grandmother. I believe she made potions and traveled with a group but I don't think she was closely related to the family. The group performed somehow (I'm thinking circus-like but not sure).

She could see visions, I think in fire, a mirror, and possibly dreams. At one point she leaves the group for safety (hers and theirs). She is being hunted for what she sees; I think magic is outlawed and she's trying to keep the group safe as well as escape herself.

I also remember her having to choose a road to travel, I think she was going to the capital city, which is also where the most witch hunters were.

I also think one of her visions was of a couple being attacked by either wolves being controlled by someone else or wolves that are actually demons (or something similar).

Comment: No chance it could have been the [Chain of Charms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kate_Forsyth) series, could it? Roma, a witch hunter type, Cromwellian England (not 1800s)

Comment: I don't think that's it...I pretty sure the book I remember was an adult book. I think it had a romance part to it (but I don't remember what). I'll take a look at that one to see though! And thanks!

Comment: How about http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/420181.The_White_Witch

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate because it seems to be a repeat of the same question the OP asked earlier. @ashley please confirm if this is the same story you are asking about in both questions, in which case we can merge the question. And if they aren't about the same story we can re-open this.